# ¿Puedo a un input file forzarle la ruta y el archivo a seleccionar via código?

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Saludos,

Tengo este `input` en la vista `Razor`:

```
<input type="file" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Imatge)"   id="@Html.IdFor(model => model.Imatge)" />
```

Y me pregunta va si por código `C#` en `Razor`, puedo obligarle a seleccionar un archivo en concreto de una carpeta en concreto, en lugar de que tenga que elegirlo la persona pulsando a "examinar"... etc etc.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que por razones de seguridad, esto no es posible y te pongo un ejemplo

```
<form name="foo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" value="c:/informacionpersonal.xls">
</form>
<script>document.foo.submit();</script>
```

Este trozo de código ejecutado en un browser enviaría tu información personal hacia el servidor web de alguien. Y esto no esta nada bien.
Por eso se obliga siempre a que el usuario indique cual es el archivo que va a trasferir.

Comment: Tal y como lo comentas, tiene su lógica... bueno voy a ver si alguien puede aportar alguna otra solución o algo que se nos escape a lo mejor... Gracias Weimar!

Comment: Estas en lo cierto. No es posible por motivos de seguridad. Lee http://stackoverflow.com/q/1696877/4541024 y http://stackoverflow.com/q/1017224/4541024

Comment: @Xavier, OK. está bueno este post. Y ahora sí confirmamos la sospecha. Gracias.